# Should we do more to help users understand that a question's tag list should not be a phrase?

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

A little while ago I corrected the tagging of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258740) about collision detection in C++.  It was tagged separately with [collision](/questions/tagged/collision) and [detection](/questions/tagged/detection), so I removed those and replaced them with the single tag [collision-detection](/questions/tagged/collision-detection).

I've made similar tag edits to [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043093) [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005851) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629213) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617857) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117143) in the past, all of which seem to have the same basic problem:  some people treat the tags box on the "Ask Question" page as a place to type a *phrase*, such as "c++ collision detection" or "php real string escaping" or "java iterating large file", instead of a list of independent tags.  This leads to broad tags like "string" and "file" that don't help much to categorize the question, as well as silly tags like "real" and "large" that don't make any sense on their own.

The "How to Tag" box on the "Ask Question" page does have some pertinent tips:

- favor existing popular tags; avoid creating new tags
- combine multiple words into single-words with dashes

but these assume that the user is already thinking about tags the "right" way, as independent categories for the question.  A user who writes a phrase like "java iterating large file" is thinking under a completely different mindset.  (It looks more like a search string, something you might type into Google.)

Since this seems to be a common problem, should something be added to the "Ask Question" page — either in the "How to Tag" box or near the input field itself — to remind users that tags do not form a phrase or sentence, and that each tag should stand on its own?

Comment: I think some of this may be due to tagging suggestions for lower-rep users. The system doesn't always know the difference between a keyword and a conversational word. A particularly awful problem is when a new user types `SQL` into their question, they get suggested `mysql` and `sql-server` and usually choose both tags (even though their question very rarely involves both).

Answer (score 3):

The [What are Tags, and How Should I Use Them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) topic in the help center says this:

> Each question may only contain 5 tags at a maximum, so choose the ones
> that best describe your question. Spaces are not allowed in tags –
> create compound tags using hyphens rather than spaces (like
> [visual-studio]) rather than multiple tags separated by spaces
> ([visual] [studio]).

When you ask a new question as a low-rep user, you get this in the sidebar:

> #### How to Tag A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions.
>
> ► favor existing popular tags; avoid creating new tags
>
> ► use common abbreviations
>
> ► don't include synonyms
>
> ► combine multiple words into single-words with dashes
>
> ► maximum of 5 tags, 25 chars per tag
>
> ► tag characters: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]
>
> ► delimit tags by space, semicolon, or comma

Is that sufficient guidance?  Well, it might be the best we can do with new users.

I've frequented several Stack Exchange sites besides Stack Overflow.  I've even asked questions on a few.  Tagging is always a bit of a struggle for me; each site has different conventions and ideas about what kinds of tags are good and what kinds of tags are bad.

Overall, the tagging system works better than I would expect such an ad-hoc tagging system to work, given the number of new folks who come here every day.

Comment: Worth noting: the word "delimit" works in instructions for a programming site, but the word "separate" would probably be better for non-programming sites.